# jQuery select next div element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

structure:

```
<div id="XY">
    <p>Test</p>
    <ul>
       <li>Test<a class="link"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My goal is to get the ID of the div and insert it into the link of the "link" item.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".link").attr("href", "open_" + $(this).parent("div").attr('id'));
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".link").attr("href", "open_" + $(".link").closest("div").attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="XY">
    <p>Test</p>
    <ul>
       <li>Test<a class="link"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In case you have more links for which this should apply, just use `each()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".link").each(function() {
      $(this).attr("href", "open_" + $(this).closest("div").attr('id'));
   });
});
```

Comment: var counter = 0;
          $(".ruleLink").each(function() {
           $(this).attr("href", "#open_" + $(this).closest("div").attr("id") + "_" + counter);
           $(this).next("blockquote").attr("id", "open_" + $(this).closest("div").attr("id") + "_" + counter);
           $(this).next("blockquote").html("<b>" + $(this).text() + "</b><br />" + $(this).next("blockquote").html())
           $(this).next("blockquote").hide();
           counter++;
          });

it works, with <div><p></p><ul><li><a ...></li></ul></div> but not in a normal <div><p><a ...></p></div>.
idea?

Comment: @FelixS.I think a <p> can't contain a <blockquote> element, therefore it's not working. If you check https://jsfiddle.net/o3hLqd86/ with the DOM inspector, you'll notice that the blockquote is not inside the <p> element like it's written, but instead located below the <p> as browsers tend to correct invalid HTML. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p a <p> can only contain phrasing content and blockquote doesn't belong to that.